# Running a Java Class in Ubuntu with Virtual Box

Tags: java, unix, package

Since I'm quite new in Java i have a question. As told on the title , I run an Ubuntu Server on VirtualBox and I have a problem running a very simple class with the use of package.

I give you the code:

```
package world;

public class HelloWorld{

public static void main (String[] args){

System.out.println("Hello World")
}
}
```

Very simple code indeed. After compiling it with `javac HelloWorld.java`, with no mistakes (ok now what mistakes could possible find),

- Running `java HelloWorld`, gives me the message NoClassDefFoundError
- Running `java world.HelloWorld` returns cannot find or load main class.

I suspect that it has something to do with classpath , but I cannot find an answer.

Comment: What kind of server are you running? Ubuntu is an OS not a server.

Answer (score 1):

It's a classpath issue. You can probably check to see what your classpath is by looking at the `CLASSPATH` environment variable. You can try adding the directory your classfiles are at to the end of this CLASSPATH, but the simplest thing to do is probably the following.

Make sure the `HelloWorld.java` file is in a directory called `world`, and you can compile is like:

```
javac world/HelloWorld.java
```

This will create a `HelloWorld.class` file in the world directory. You can then try running

```
java world.HelloWorld
```

or

```
java -classpath . world.HelloWorld
```

from the same place.

You can also use the `-d` flag with javac to put the class files in a different place instead of the same place the source (.java files) are.